# How to use "changed after" in jql query for custom fields in jira

Tags: jira, jql

This is my JQL query

```
    "project = HOTFIX and type != Task "
    "AND AUTOMATION_STATUS in ('Build In Progress', 'Build Queued', 'Release In Progress') "
    "AND NOT AUTOMATION_STATUS changed after 12h
```

I'm getting this error
History searches do not support the  'AUTOMATION_STATUS' field.

here AUTOMATION_STATUS is a custom field, how can I modify my query for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CHANGED operator doesn't work with custom field. It works only with the Assignee, Fix Version, Priority, Reporter, Resolution, and Status fields.
[See reference](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/jql-operators/#CHANGED)